# Simil-group-by on filename patterns in bash

Tags: bash

Given a set of files, whose filename follow the following pattern:

```
PREFIX_{id}_{timestamp}.xml
```

I'd like to select (and move) for each `id` the file with the most recent `timestamp` (formatted as `yyyyMMddHHmmss`)

What is an efficient way? So far I came up with:

```sh
ls PREFIX_* \
    | cut -d '_' -f2 \
    | sort | uniq \
    | xargs -I {} sh -c 'ls PREFIX_{}_* | tail -n1' | xargs -I {} cp {} /other/dir
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ ls PREFIX* | sort -t_ -k2,2 -k3,3nr | awk -F_ '!a[$2]++'
```

sort by id and by time in reverse order, pick the first one (the latest timestamp) with `awk`.